# Unable to change almost any configuration from my desktop

Tags: unity, nvidia, 14.04, lubuntu, configuration

first, apologies for my english.

Well, my problem is that if I can't change any configuration.

some examples:

1-can't unlock any apps from the Launcher.
2-can't disable online searchs on the Dash.
3-can't change the desktop background
(some details on this: I actually tried to cheat the system and I renamed one of the jpg files that were in /usr/share/backgrounds and now the background is black.)
4-can't change any parameters from the mouse & touchpad.

well... I can keep trying to change things but I think that the point is clear.

Some things that do change are the resolution of the screen and the volume.

I also tried to use programs to modify the configuration but no luck either.
The programs are: Unity Tweak tool, compizconfig-settings-manager and alternatives configurator.

Some relevant info:
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 (64), yesterday I did a fresh install of it. Previously I had Ubuntu 13.10 and decided to install win7 and Ubuntu 14.04 because sometimes I need excel and other things. I installed win7 first and then Ubuntu with a burned DVD. When I rebooted the screen got freezed after the login. I had experimented this problem before and my last solution was to switch linux kernels (to al older one) at start up and don't install propietary drivers. Now I did not had that option so I proved a lot of things, the final changes were that now I'm using linux kernel 3.14.3-031403-generic and open source drivers.

My laptop is a Dell Vostro 3400 with a i5 processor and a GeForce 310M graphic card. I also changed the HHD for a SSD.

I think that the problem is related with the fact that I installed lubuntu-desktop package to have a graphical interface to solve my problems with unity.

That's it. I would ask to deliver a solution that is not reinstall ubuntu (if posible) because it took me many hours to be able to log in. Unless there's anyone who can make the installation work with no problems in less than a couple of hours.

again, forgive my for the bad english.

Thanks in advice.
Ignacio

EDIT:
I solved the problem. I will post the steps here, maybe someone could use them.

1.Fresh install. Roboot
2.Find that I have the same problem that before, reboot in recovery mode.
3.Conect via cable, activate the netwoprking
4.Open a root shell: sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade
5. (many useless things) 
6. Then, in a console:

sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current
sudo reboot

and worked like a charm

Comment: It may seem strange to do so, but you should copy your solution into an answer to your own question.